# Enitity Framework и Using

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Подскажите, а является ли нормальной практикой плодить контексты using при работе с Enitity Framework или правильнее передавать объекты сущностей в методы в качестве аргументов?

Вот это я подразумеваю под "Плодить контексты":

```
DoWork()
{
    using (var db = new Entity())
    {
        // какая-то работа с сущностью
        ...
        DoWork2();
        ...
        // какая-то работа с сущностью
    }
}

DoWork2()
{
    using (var db = new Entity())
    {
        // какая-то работа с сущностью
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: лучше узнать что такое паттерн "репозиторий" и подумать над грамотной архитектурой приложения.

Comment: @gromanev: Репозиторий и EF как-то не очень сочетаются, на мой взгляд.

Comment: @VladD я с EF не работал -- расскажите, почему не сочетаются (можно в чатик).

Comment: @andreycha: У нас тут где-то было обсуждение по этому поводу, сейчас попробую найти.

Comment: @VlaD ну тогда и разработчикам nopCommerce об этом скажите ;)

Comment: @gromanev: nopCommerce? В первый раз слышу об этом проекте.

Comment: Дискуссия по поводу того, нужен ли репозиторий с EF, ведётся [в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37682/orm-vs-repository).

Comment: Если внутри вызываемого метода с сущностью не происходит изменений - то передавать сущность и не плодить контексты. Если изменения есть - открывать контекст заново или же передать контекст в качестве параметра в метод (так тоже можно). Множественное открытие контекстов рано или поздно может привести к непредвиденным обстоятельствам.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

У многих, кто использует EF, возникает вопрос, как часто мы должны создавать `DbContext`, как определить оптимальное время жизни контекста.
Возможные варианты времени жизни контекста:

- Функция
- Форма
- Поток
- Приложение

Чтобы сделать правильный выбор, предлагаю рассмотреть несколько аспектов:

1. **Правильное разрушение контекста (вызов метода `Dispose()` контекста)**
    Вызов метода
   Dispose является важным шагом при работе с классом `DbContext`. Используя
   конструкцию `using`, гарантируетcя своевременный вызов метода `Dispose` и тем самым
   освобождение неуправляемых ресурсов.

   ```
   using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext()) 
   { 
     … 
   }
   ```

   Если забыть вызвать `Dispose`, то это может привести к утечке открытых соединений к БД и к неосвобождению неуправляемых ресурсов.
   [do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html#.U9efX_ldXpo)
2. **Стоимость операции создания нового класса контекста**
   Операция создания нового контекста недорогая, потому что это, в основном, копирование ссылок метаданных из глобального кеша. Поэтому за стоимость этой операции не стоит беспокоиться.
3. **Использование памяти**
   Чем дольше вы используете объект `DbContext`, тем больше памяти он занимает. Потому что он будет содержать все сущности (entity), о которых он знает, которые были запрошены через запросы, были добавлены либо присоединены. Поэтому держать долго контекст не рекомендуется.
4. **Потокобезопасность**
   Класс `DbContext` не является потокобезопасным. Если мы используем контекст из нескольких потоков, то мы сами должны обеспечить сихронизацию доступа к контексту.
5. **Синхронизация данных с базой данных**
   После создания контекста, если не предпринимать дополнительные меры, контекст не видит изменённые данные в БД, которые были сделаны извне. Создавая новый контекст, меры по синхронизации данных с БД предпринимать не нужно.

Вот основные аспекты, которые пришли в голову. Поэтому контексты с коротким временем жизни при работе с EF являются нормальной практикой и часто используются при работе с EF.

Comment: Прекрасный ответ. Побольше бы тут таких...

Comment: @WalterNuss вот только он не отвечает на вопрос топикастера. Контектсы дешевые (ок), их не стоит держать дольше, чем нужно (ок). Вопрос - есть два метода, работают с сущностью (с одной и той же, судя по всему), в рамках одной операции (один посреди другого). Где в посте выше ответ - стоит в этом конкретном случае создавать еще один контекст, или нет?

Comment: @ PashaPash, я перечислил аспекты, которыми можно руководствоваться при выборе жизни контекста. Я рассмотрел не конкретный этот случай(который привел автор), а общий случай использования контекстов,  который легко проецируется на выбор жизни контекста для данных двух функций. В вашем ответе я тоже не согласен с некими рассуждениями, типа привязки к бизнес-процессу(этого в большинстве случаев недостаточно). Поэтому спасибо за ваше мнение, но думаю будет неполиткорректно дискутировать нам с вами, какой ответ лучше, а какой хуже. Думаю, автору будут полезны оба ответа.

Answer (score 12):

Context в EF, это, по сути, готовая реализация сразу нескольких паттернов:

- Repository
- Data Mapper
- Lazy Load
- ...
- [Identity Map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html)
- [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)

Последние два существенно ограничивают возможные варианты времени жизни контекста:

> Unit of Work
>
> Maintains a list of objects affected by **a business transaction** and coordinates the writing out of changes and the resolution of concurrency problems.

> Identity Map
>
> An Identity Map keeps a record of all objects that have been read from the database in **a single business transaction**. Whenever you want an object, you check the Identity Map first to see if you already have it.

Из двух цитат выше напрямую следует что контект должен жить ровно одну бизнес-операцию:

- Если он будет жить меньше ("плодить контексты" в вопросе) - то часть кода операции не увидит измененения, внесенные до нее.
- Если он будет жить дольше, на протяжении нескольких операций - то другие операции будут видеть неактуальные данные (из-за Identity Map) или наоборот, будт видеть изменения, которые еще не были сохранены.

Что такое бизнес-операция (бизнес-транзакция) - зависит от конкретной предметной области. Это не транзакция в терминах баз данных, а более широкое понятие - некое целостное действие в терминах предметной области.

Обычно это вызов кода сервиса / фасада в BL - `DoWork`, где Work - это какая-то цельная операция, действие. Т.е. обычно это вызов функции верхнего уровня в вашем приложении.

---

Соображения использования памяти, потокобезопасности, стоимости создания, синхронизации с базой данных - полностью вторичны, и не должны служить основанием для выбора времени жизни контекста.

Контекст - это попытка отразить в коде цельную операцию из предметной области. Предметной области все равно, сделаете вы это в одном потоке или в разных, потратите при этом много памяти или мало, придется ли вам при этом писать огромные методы, или обойдеться парой строк - это никак не влияет на целостность операции. Соответственно, и на выбор времени жизни контекста влиять не должно.

Выбор контейнера в коде, в рамках которого живет контектст - функция, форма, поток, запрос, приложение - тоже вторичен. Он должне быть следствием, а не причиной времени жизни контекста.

- Если конкретная функция (`DoWork`) соответствует бизнес-операции - она должна контролировать время жизни контекста. Если нет (`DoWork2`) - то нет.
- Если бизнес-операция растягивается на время отображения формы - то время жизни контекста должно совпадать с формой, и контекст вполне может быть полем формы. Если нет - то нет.
- Если вы запускаете фоновые операция в отдельном потоке - то время жизни скорее всего совпадет с временем жизни потока. Но не потому, что это *фоновая* операция, а потому что это фоновая *операция*.
- Если у вас консольное приложение, которое выполняет ровно одну бизнес-операцию - то вполне разумно использовать один контекст на приложение.

Comment: <Если он будет жить дольше, на протяжении нескольких операций - то другие операции будут видеть неактуальные данные (из-за Identity Map) или наоборот, будт видеть изменения, которые еще не были сохранены.> 
- поправлю: если эти другие операции работать будут с тем же контекстом, то работать будут с актуальными данными, даже формально не выложенными пока в базу. При первом сохранении контекста - будут сохранены все изменения. Просто при наличии такого межоперационного контекста - не нужно открывать новые (на те же данные)

Comment: @ale да, но изменения которые еще не были сохранены, могут так и не быть сохранены никогда - например, из-за провала optimistic concurrency check, Или потому, что код в бизнес логике передумал их сохранять. Я просто не смог придумать аналога слова "актуальные" для данных, которые уже есть, но "актуальными" еще не стали. В любом случае, делать межоперационный контекст - это то же самое, как работать с базой в read uncommitted. Учитывая копеечную цену создания контекста - оно того не стоит.

Comment: PashaPash♦, вы действительно считаете что контекст в EF это готовая реализация всех этих паттернов?

Comment: @СергейИгнахин да. выберите любой из них - и я вам подробно расскажу, как именно он проявляется в EF. Со ссылками на Фаулера.

Comment: @PashaPash♦, какие то проявления не говорят о том что он их реализует. Это всего лишь похожие моменты. А иначе не было бы смысла в реализации паттернов отдельно)

Comment: @СергейИгнахин давайте продолжим в чате -
 https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71828/discussion-between-pashapash-and--

Answer (score 2):

Ну а с другой стороны: 
Если загрузка каких-то объектов из базы и их изменение с сохранением происходит в разных местах приложения и еще и по инициативе пользователя, т.е. может быть значительно разнесено по времени - то придётся каждый раз при создании контекста снова загружать нужные объекты, например используя метод Find с сохраненным ранее ключом и работать уже с обновленными объектами. Если же контекст держать открытым, то этого не потребуется. Только нужно будет поработать над гарантированным закрытием этого долгоживущего контекста как только он перестанет быть нужным. Наверно тут нужен компромис - может быть кэш с выгрузкой контекста (контекстов) по времени, хотя это не проще, чем многократная загрузка объектов, но производительнее.

Comment: Можно не загружать снова те же объекты, а к новому контексту приаттачить ранее загруженный объект -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271(v=vs.100).aspx