# Как правильно инициализировать DBContext в WPF приложении с использованием MVVM-паттерна?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Где инициализировать DBContext (`DB = new DBContext()`), чтобы не нарушать принципы и правила MVVM-паттерна в WPF приложении?

Приложение состоит из главного окна MainWindow с управляемыми(дочерними) UserControl:

```
<Window x:Class="TestManager.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestManager.View"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestManager.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Склад" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewModelPeople}">
            <local:ViewPeople/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewModelMainLogs}">
            <local:ViewMainLogs/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Pages"  Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

***ViewModelMainWindow.cs:***

```
    class ViewModelMainWindow : ViewModelBase
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Выбранный UserControl
    /// </summary>
    private object selectedViewModel;

    public object SelectedViewModel
    {
        get { return selectedViewModel; }
        set { selectedViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedViewModel"); }
    }

    public ViewModelMainWindow()
    {
        SelectedViewModel = new ViewMainLogs(); //Инициализация при запуске приложения
    }
}
```

*P.s. насколько правильно и логично использовать один экземпляр DBContext для всего проекта?*

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/506887/218063

Answer (score 0):

В MVVM база данных — это модель. Соответственно и инициализировать её нужно там. И раз работа с базой данных обычно медленная, а EF не многопоточный, то инициализировать нужно в том потоке, в котором вы будете работать с базой (и это должен быть не главный поток).

Comment: По поводу контекста, я слыхал правило «один контекст на одну логическую операцию». Но ни подтвердить, ни опровергнуть не могу.