# WPF/ASP.NET, Entity Framework ,DbContext и нужно ли вызывать Dispose?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, entity-framework

Вот и меня настиг этот довольно спорный вопрос. Когда я начал изучать этот вопрос то мне везде попадались примеры с использованием **using**.
Например как здесь [Enitity Framework и Using](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506887/enitity-framework-%D0%B8-using/507901).
Я являюсь програмистом wpf приложений и когда начал изучать Entity у меня был опыт с его предшественником с DataSet и TableAdapter. Тут было достаточно просто так как DataSet/DataTable может жить отдельно от TableAdapter и все изменения фиксируются в нем. То есть я могу привязать DataTable напрямую к любому DataGrid и вызывать TableAdapter для обновлений в любое время тут же его уничтожая чтобы закрывать соединения и! при этом не писав репозитории на каждый чих изменений. DataGrid меняя строки вызывал события изменений данных в DataSet, а он сам уже создавал TableAdapter и сохранял изменения в базу.

Но в Entity все не так, и у меня это вызывает большой дискомфорт. В большинстве примерах пишутся репозитории в которых оборачивается DbContext который тут же уничтожается. И это повлекло за собой что я писал на каждый чих CRUD обработку событий DataGrid где он бы вызывал этот репозиторий для сохранения изменений.

Начав копать глубже я нашел пару статей. В которых это опровергалось. И утверждалось что DbContext сам закрывает соединения когда запрос выполнился.

[Номер один](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/359667/is-it-ok-to-create-an-entity-framework-datacontext-object-and-dispose-it-in-a-us)

[Номер два](https://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext/)

Еще немного поискав я нашел, что и для ASP.NET MVC так же не требуются репозитории, так как контроллер уничтожается после обработки запроса и в некоторых фреимворках так же есть подобные DataGrid. Они отправляют события изменения данных и самому почти ничего не нужно писать для большинства случаев.

Попробовав написать без репозитория - создав один раз DbContext и не закрывающем его на всем протяжении работы приложения это сильно облегчило работу. Коллекции не уничтожаются, они связаны с контекстом который сам отправляет изменения. Но возникла небольшая проблема когда приложение работает очень долго при возобновлении работы вылетает исключение. Незнаю чем это вызвано. Думаю нужно просто отловить исключение, заного создать контекст и привязать все коллекции.

Вопрос в том - как же всё-таки удобнее и правильнее использовать контекст?
С репозиториями/без или есть еще вариант по вашему?

Comment: DbContext должен жить короткое время и тут дело скорее не в соединениях, а в отслеживании сущностей которыми он оперирует. Я знаю такое правило, для веб приложения для каждого запроса должен создаваться свой DbContext. Для десктопа для каждого окна свой DbContext, но тут нюанс, если окно долгоживущее, то желательно DbContext  создавать для каких то конкретных операций или групп операций, а потом прибивать.

Comment: А вообще это дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506887/enitity-framework-%d0%b8-using?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @PavelPopov дак почему если есть опровергающие это статьи, и почему не предположить что он сам очищает изменения? нету же вроде бы доказательств что он всю жизнь хранит эти все изменения

Comment: А где вы нашли опровержение ? например по первой ссылке "Номер один 1" вполне резонный ответ "DbContext is a lightweight object; it is designed to be used once per business transaction. Making your DbContext a Singleton and reusing it throughout the application can cause other problems, like concurrency and memory leak issues." что я и написал

Comment: @PavelPopov это не дубликат я пытаюсь узнать есть ли что то отличное от этого тупого using и бесконечных репозиториев. У меня один DbContext потому что я использую одну базу и все нужные таблицы загнал туда. Я не работал в крупных компаниях поэтому мне неоткуда больше узнать как же совместить удобство и расширяемость.

Comment: @PavelPopov и ниже от этого написано не удалять DbContext самому

Comment: Вы пытаетесь решить сразу несколько вопрсов: нужен ли репозиторий - это один большой вопрос. Кратко отвечу так по сути для простых решений не нужен, это просто надстройка над DbContext, который зачастую просто пробрасывает обращение к DbContext. Главным арг в пользу репозитория по верх DbContext  - возможность быстрой смены источника данных, например сменить то же EF на NHibernate ответе вам это нужно ?

Comment: "не удалять DbContext" я полагаю там это написано в контексте использования IoC контейнеров. В момент запроса в контроллер через конструктор инжектится DbContext и при завершении запроса IoC контейнер сам вызовет Dispose

Comment: @PavelPopov но еще без репозитория код обработки изменений будет лежать во view что тоже неочень, поэтому я его использовал хоть и нехотя пока не проверил держать открытым DbContext

Comment: @PavelPopov хорошо я поищу про утечки памяти в англоязычных статьях, раз вы утверждаете что они критичны

Comment: Зачем далеко ходить, почитайте [от создателей](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext)  раздел "Время существования" и особенно пункт "При работе с долго выполняемым контекстом учитывайте следующее" там все прекрасно расписано

Comment: @PavelPopov нет ничгео там не прекрасно расписано, единственное что увидел это почему для каждой формы отдельный контекст, но когда! его уничтожать если у меня долгоживущие окна и например приложение вообще может быть открыто сутками подрят просто потому что пользователь так захотел, то есть сказано что я могу (как я выше описал) создать его и не закрывать ожидая событий от view компонентов, но когда закрывать? так же как я и предположил? ловить странное исключение когда у меня программа на следующие сутки падает?